# Error Lnk2019 while installing pyjnius

Tags: java, python

I am getting this error as follows:

> jnius.obj : error LNK2019 : unresolved external symbol _JNI_CreateJavaVM@12...

what am I missing here and why am I getting this message?

Comment: Add more details to your post: OS, Python version, lib version....

Comment: I am using python 3.4, cython 0.23.1, and MS VC++ 10 on windows 7.